# How to store two differents Graphs into one with Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For a later traitements with The project [CAPS](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark) , I need to store 2 different Graphs into one:

`Graph3=Graph1+Graph2`

I tried to search for solutions to do that and I found `UNION ALL` but the last doesn't work as I expected. Is there another way to do that with Cypher?

## Example :

```
val Graph1=session.cypher("""
                            | FROM GRAPH mergeGraph
                            | MATCH (from)-[via]->(to)
                            |WHERE substring(from.geohash,0,5)=substring(to.geohash,0,5)
                            | CONSTRUCT
                            |  CREATE (h1:HashNode{geohash:substring(from.geohash,0,5)})-[COPY OF via]->(h1)
                            | RETURN GRAPH
                             """.stripMargin).graph
```

which contains this pattern :

[image]

```
val Graph2=session.cypher("""
                            | FROM GRAPH mergeGraph
                            | MATCH (from)-[via]->(to)
                            |WHERE substring(from.geohash,0,5)<>substring(to.geohash,0,5)
                            | CONSTRUCT
                            |  CREATE (:HashNode{geohash:substring(from.geohash,0,5)})-[COPY OF via]->(:HashNode{geohash:substring(to.geohash,0,5)})
                            | RETURN GRAPH
                             """.stripMargin).graph
```

which contains this pattern :

[image]

With union All :

```
Graph3=Graph1.unionAll(Graph2)
```

I get this graph  :

[image]

As you can see the green nodes are the nodes of Graph2 without relationship ! thats what i didn't expected.

Comment: Can you add more explain? what you mean by 2 different graphs? please add an example of Graph1, Graph2 and your expect result Graph3

Comment: I'm still confused about what the problem is. Is the problem that the TRIP relationships from Graph2 were lost in the unionAll? If Graph1 and Graph2 give the correct results, it sounds like a bug in unionAll dropping relationships from the second graph.

Comment: @Tazra the problem is as you mentioned. i don't know if that is a problem of unionAll or not.